# How to use useState and useEffect to filter data

Tags: reactjs

I created a drop-down form which will switch views between data obtained from an API. The current view is set to view all incoming queues, but how can I filter the results to show a selection of queues based on the incoming “u_react_view” field category (type string)? I’m fairly new to hooks and any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

XML response for all queues: <u_react_view>all</u_react_view>

XML response for servicedesk queues: <u_react_view>all, servicedesk</u_react_view>

```
const App = () => {
    const [results, setResults] = useState([]) 
  
    useEffect(()=>{
      axios.get('API LINK')
        .then(res => {
          setResults(res.data.result)
        });
    },[]);
  
    const Filter = () => {
      return (
        <form className="filter">
            <select name="filter" id="filter"> 
            <option value="all">All Queues View</option>
            <option value="servicedesk">Service Desk View</option>
        </select>
        </form>
      )
    }
  
    const Results = () => {
        return (
            <>
            {
                results.map(i => (
                    <ul>
                        <li key={i.sys_id}><h1>{i.u_queues}</h1></li>
                    </ul>
                ))
            }
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post what you have in `res.data.result`

Comment: This is one result:
`
1. sys_created_by: "jbun"
2. sys_created_on: "2020-10-06 21:27:25"
3. sys_id: "890cbcccdb7b1450bb8e5b7a68961916"
4. sys_mod_count: "396466"
5. sys_tags: ""
6. sys_updated_by: "system"
7. sys_updated_on: "2021-02-25 03:06:51"
8. u_agents_available: ""
9. u_billable_tickets_closed_last_month: ""
10. u_billable_tickets_closed_mtd: ""
11. u_calls_in_queue: "0"
12. u_calls_taken_last_month: "925"
13. u_calls_taken_mtd: "713"
14. u_company: ""
15. u_queues: "All Energy"
16. u_react_view: "all, servicedesk"
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I under stand you should filter the results based on the filter selected.

to do that use below code it will set the state and assign value back to `select`

```
// for storing selected filter
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState('all')


<select value={filter} onChange={(e)=> setFilter(e.target.value)}> 
    <option value="all">All Queues View</option>
    <option value="servicedesk">Service Desk View</option>
</select>
```

Now filter the results and render the results list

```
const Results = () => {
    return (
        <ul>
         {
            results.filter(result => results.u_react_view.includes(filter)).map(i => (         
               <li key={i.sys_id}><h1>{i.u_queues}</h1></li>         
            ))
        }
       </ul>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]) 
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState('all')
  useEffect(()=>{
    axios.get('API LINK')
      .then(res => {
        setResults(res.data.result)
      });
  },[]);

  return (
      <>
      <select onChange={(e)=> setFilter(e.target.value)}> 
          <option selected={filter === 'all'} value="all">All Queues View</option>
          <option selected={filter === 'servicedesk'} value="servicedesk">Service Desk View</option>
      </select>
      {
          results.filter(item=> {
            if(filter === 'servicedesk' && item.type !== 'servicedesk'){
              return false
            }
            return true
          }).map(i => (
              <ul>
                  <li key={i.sys_id}><h1>{i.u_queues}</h1></li>
              </ul>
          ))
      }
      </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. When it gets to the <option selected={filter... portion, this error occurs: TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined